# compare and insert only new records to sqlite database

Tags: database, sqlite, insert

I have sqlite local database. I want to insert only fresh data from remote server  to local database.Since there is no time field,it is difficult to insert only new records.How can i acheive this? I require this for my hybrid mobile app. Any helps apperciated..Thanks in advance.

Two tables:

my local db table is

```
tbl_orders
 id      name      age
  1       yyy       30
  2       xxx       20
```

my remote db table is

```
tbl_orders
 id      name      age
 1       yyy       36
 2       xxx       20
 3       vvv       40
 4       zzz       37
```

In the above the remote table contains additionally two records and also the value in first record(age column) get changed.now i want to insert and update this(i.e 1st,3rd,4th) to my local sqlite table without deleting and reinserting the whole table.

Comment: Your local table is completely slave respect to remote table? (reading your sample yes)

Answer (score 0):

Your table is replicated in two DB?

If yes, you can do an INSERT with NOT EXISTS clause in WHERE condition. Alternatively, add datetime field in your source table.

Another way:
Add a boolean field in your source DB (fl_sent), populated by a trigger when create a new row in your DB or update them. Default value is false, and when you want to syncronize your DBs your select is based on this field

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE fl_sent = 0
```

For a more complete answer please post your tables.

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT:**

Solution 1:
Add field date in your remote table (source) (if you want, you write a trigger about toggle this field) and then execute your sendable query based on this date.

Solution 2:
Add field flag (fl_sent) set by zero (if you want, you write a trigger about toggle this field) and then execute your sendable query based on this flag.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `UNIQUE` constrain in `id`.

Redefining your local table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_orders(UNIQUE id, name, age);
```

or without redefining table

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbl_orders_id ON tbl_orders(id);
```

With constrain, your updates become a single statement:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO local.tbl_orders SELECT * FROM remote.tbl_orders;
```